# Process exists action in utility general VBO in Blueprism

Tags: blueprism

If I wanted to check if an application is already open or not, how can we check that with process exists action in utility VBO in Blueprism? It is asking for process name when I go with process exists action as input. I have given a process name where we can see it in the task manager but it is not producing the desired results.

For an example, if I want to launch a Google page through BluePrism but it is already open, now I want to know whether this Google page is open or not. For this we can use Utility VBO but I am not getting it.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

"Process exist" action allows you to check if the process with this name is running right now in windows. To use that, you need to have a proper, process name. For example for internet explorer it's "iexplore", and for MS Excel it's just "excel".

Using this action you can get only understanding if the process exists or not, and nothing more.

If you'd like to know if the webpage google.pl had opened, then you'll need to use other techniques - namely using application modeler, spying windows and using a variety of blueprism actions.

Answer (score 0):

While launching any web application, BOT should attach the process to window/application, if attach action returns false then only BOT need to launch the site in IE. For Attach action there will be different inputs are available some of them are listed below:

1. ProcessName
2. WindowText